# GD Star rating plugin of WordPress is not getting loaded on the page

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to use GD star rating plugin in my website but even after correct installation and configuration. Plugin is not getting loaded on the page.

I have tried several things but none of them worked. Please suggest what i can do here??

Website Link- http://accesstowerhire.co.uk/

Screenshot link- http://awesomescreenshot.com/0981gmy398

Plugin is there at the bottom of the page.

Please help!

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Can any one help me on this?? :-(

Comment: No body has any clue about this??

Answer (score 0):

It could be a cache plugin you are using. I know there is a problem with the WP Super Cache plugin.

You could also try disabling the cache plugins support which is in the plugins settings panel -> tab features -> cache support